# Build a file diagram for an R code

Tags: r, rstudio, diagram, call-graph

I need to work on a relatively large R code written by someone else. The code has no documentation, and it's split into countless files, each one of which can contain one or more functions. The original author didn't use a Makefile, so there's no documentation on what's calling what.

As a first step, I'd like to build a dendrogram. I mean a tree whose root is the main file, the interior nodes are the various files called,  and the leaves (terminal nodes) are files which don't call functions defined in other files. Is there a way to do that automatically? A picture output would be great, but even a text file would do. R Studio solutions would also be ok.

**EDIT**: apparently my description is not clear enough, thus I add a very simple (trivial, actually) example. Assume I have 4 source files `main.r`, `foo.r`, `bar.r` and `blargh.r`, all in the same folder (the real case has ~50 files all "tidily" stored in the same ruddy folder, together with input/output files). The content of `main.r` is:

```
# main.r
source("foo.r")
source("bar.r")
source("blargh.r")

foo()
bar()
```

`foo.r`:

```
# foo.r
foo <- function(){
    print("I'm foo")
    blargh()
}
```

`bar.r`:

```
# bar.r
bar <- function(){
    print("I'm bar")
    blargh()
}
```

`blargh.r`

```
# blargh.r
blargh <- function(){
    print("I'm blargh")
}
```

What I need to generate is a diagram like this:

```
  main.r
   ¦--foo.r                 
   ¦   ¦       
   ¦   °--blargh.r       
   ¦       
   °--bar.r                 
       ¦    
       °--blargh.r
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that the `path` contains the all the sub-directories and files,

```
files <- list.files(path, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
#for eg.
files<- c(
    "root/dir1/some/file1.R", 
    "root/dir1/another1/file2.R", 
    "root/dir1/another1/new/file3.R", 
    "root/dir2/some/data1.csv", 
    "root/dir2/more/data2.csv"
)
```

Now you have all your files, in `files` variable.

```
library(data.tree)
library(plyr)

a <- lapply(strsplit(files, "/"), function(z) as.data.frame(t(z)))
a <- rbind.fill(a)
mytree <- data.tree::as.Node(data.frame(pathString = path))
plot(mytree)

1  root                  
2   ¦--dir1                 
3   ¦   ¦--some          
4   ¦   ¦   °--file1.R    
5   ¦   °--another1       
6   ¦       ¦--file2.R    
7   ¦       °--new      
8   ¦           °--file3.R
9   °--dir2                 
10      ¦--some          
11      ¦   °--data1.csv  
12      °--more          
13          °--data2.csv
```

Note : This structure is called a [dendogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrogram). 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I think it should be `strsplit(files, "/")`, not `strsplit(path, "/")`, right?

Comment: sorry, it doesn't answer my questions. I'm not trying to find in which directory each file is (they're all in the same folder, to add mess to mess!!). I need to understand which file is calling which file. Wait a bit, I'm trying to build a test case.

Comment: check out https://blogisticreflections.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/r-function-of-the-day-foodweb/

Comment: @DeltaIV , I've found a `list.functions.in.file()` under `NCmisc` package, refer [her e](https://rdrr.io/cran/NCmisc/man/list.functions.in.file.html) and working around it.

Comment: @BenBolker, `foodweb` looks likt it could be of help to me. However, the code isn't an R package: of course, someone who's not going to bother writing documentation, is definitely not going to bother putting all of his code into a nice, neat R package. Thus I'm not sure what the `where` argument of `foodweb` should be. I'm currently running the code (it will take quite some time) and I will try to run `foodweb` after the code has run, so the functions (at least the highest level ones) should be in the Global Environment.

Comment: @ParthChaudhary, that sounds good! Looking forward to seeing your updated answer.